# How do we use IBM Appid to auth Kibana users ?

Tags: ibm-appid

Has anyone used IBM AppID on IBM Bluemix.net to auth Kibana users ?
We found this tutorial which uses keycloak, we assume IBM Appid is a similar configuration ?

Comment: Which tutorial? Where and how is Kibana used?

Answer (score 1):

Following this blog, you can use the Bell plugin with Kibana to create a custom App Id authentication strategy: https://steemit.com/kibana/@r351574nc3/2am2se-effing-better-auth-with-oauth2-for-elk

Example config:

```
    server.auth.strategy('appid', 'bell', {
        config: {
            authHost: appid.providerHost,
            userInfoUrl: appid.userInfoUrl
        },
        location: appid.redirectUri,
        password: appid.password,
        provider: appid.provider,
        clientId: appid.clientId,
        clientSecret: appid.clientSecret,
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick update.. A couple of options: 1)  Search-Guard product, 2) X-Pack or 3)  ReadonlyREST (not verified).

And no, there is no free lunch. The OpenSource (Basic) edition does not include Security features you're looking for. The most popular approach, in case if you want to stick with free components, is to put another reverse proxy before the Kibana and do authentication there. Both Apache and Nginx do have modules and solutions that would allow you to do authentication and AppID integration. It is relatively easy if you know what you do. Otherwise, prepare for a bumpy road and that's one of the reasons why aforementioned solutions (X-Pack, SG, ReadonlyREST) might be worth paying for.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is correct. Both App ID and KeyCloak are OAuth2 and OpenID Connect providers. The major difference between them is the fact that KeyCloak is manage-it-yourself software product, while App ID is a fully managed service.

KeyCloak provides a KeyCloak Gatekeeper container image that you should be able to configure as an authentication proxy in front of Kibana and use App ID as your identity provider.

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_keycloak_generic_adapter
[image]

There are also some other OIDC proxies you might be able to use as well.